# How to determine if a type implements an interface in Powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, envdte

I have a Member class in a project. I find this class by using powershell on package manager console in Visual Studio.

```
public class Member : ICacheable
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    ...
}
```

It prints something like below. How to check this class is assignable to ICacheable or not. Actaully I am trying to find all the classes that implements ICacheable but I couldnt find any property that will help me to find this.

```
IsDirty              : False
FileCount            : 1
Name                 : Member.cs
Collection           : System.__ComObject
Properties           : System.__ComObject
DTE                  : System.__ComObject
Kind                 : {6BB5F8EE-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}
ProjectItems         : System.__ComObject
Object               : System.__ComObject
ExtenderNames        : {}
ExtenderCATID        : {610D4615-D0D5-11D2-8599-006097C68E81}
Saved                : True
ConfigurationManager : 
FileCodeModel        : System.__ComObject
Document             : System.__ComObject
SubProject           : 
ContainingProject    : System.__ComObject
```

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

Note: $memberItem is a ProjectItem that I showed you at above.

```
$memberItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements | % { $_.Children | % { $_.ImplementedInterfaces } }


DTE           : System.__ComObject
Collection    : System.__ComObject
Name          : ICacheable
FullName      : ApplicationBase.Core.Interface.ICacheable
ProjectItem   : 
Kind          : 8
IsCodeType    : True
InfoLocation  : 2
Children      : 
Language      : {B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}
StartPoint    : 
EndPoint      : 
ExtenderNames : {ExternalLocation}
ExtenderCATID : 
Parent        : System.__ComObject
Namespace     : System.__ComObject
Bases         : System.__ComObject
Members       : System.__ComObject
Access        : 1
Attributes    : System.__ComObject
DocComment    : 
Comment       : 
DerivedTypes  : 
IsGeneric     : False
DataTypeKind  : 1
Parts         :
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how things work in the package manager console, but in powershell you can check if a compiled(and loaded) type implements interfaces using the `implementedinterfaces` property. Ex. with `array`-type:

```
#[array].ImplementedInterfaces.Contains([System.Collections.ICollection])
[array].ImplementedInterfaces.Contains([type]"System.Collections.Icollection")
True
```

You can see all implemented interfaces with:

```
[array].ImplementedInterfaces

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ICloneable
True     False    IList
True     False    ICollection
True     False    IEnumerable
True     False    IStructuralComparable
True     False    IStructuralEquatable
```

Comment: I check, and this works on package manager console too. This gives me idea. Then I should get the type to reach the ImplementedInterfaces property. I am searching for it now.

Comment: You gave me the idea then I found the solution. I added solution to question. Thanks.